# Why abstract method cannot have an implementation inside the body?

Tags: oop, typescript

I am having a problem that i have to implement the parent method and the method has to be overriden in the child class for further implementation.
Why this happen? and Why the language like Java, Typescript, C# do not allow this?

Since many of you ask why do i need it.

I have a parent class called Component written in typescript

```
class Component {
    root : HTMLElement;
    constructor(root : HTMLElement) {
        this.root = root;
        this.decorate();
    }
    abstract decorate();
}

class Field extends Component {
    this.id;

    constructor(root : HTMLElement) {
         super(root);

    }
    decorate() {
       this.id = this.root.getAttribute(data-id);
    }
}

class InputField extends Field {
      inputField : HTMLElement;

      constructor(root : HTMLElement) {
          super(root)
      }
      //i want to force users to override this
      decorate(){
          //and to call this
          super.decorate();
          this.inputField = this.root.getElementById('input-field');
      }

}
```

Comment: Why does your method need to be abstract if it is going to have a body?

Comment: thanks for the downvote. please tell me why you give me a downvote so i could correct it

Comment: because i want to enforce the other developers to override it. @CKing

Comment: Because your question boils down to: I just bought a bike, but I don't want a bike.

Comment: i really want to know why the people who create abstract method does not allow people to implement something. it can give me some knowledges too

Comment: @RobertLimanto So what you are asking for is a method that should always be implemented by the subclass and has a body. Why does such a method need a body if you want to *enforce* it to be overriden?

Comment: because there is an implementation in the method body and it is the same across the child class. This implementation will modify the parent field  so the user of the child class may not know about this

Comment: @RobertLimanto And somehow you expect us to read your mind. Please show some code samples to support your question.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off reading through some of the design patters and then try to restructure your code fragment based on a well accepted pattern. Sounds like a structural pattern (maybe composite?), that is where I would start if I were you. http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Comment: i have updated the content

Comment: @Igor i will look through that, thanks igor

Comment: `abstract` *means* "method without a body (yet)". it means we say that the method will exist, but here we don't know exactly what it does yet, but it will be defined somewhere else.

Comment: So, you want to have a method, which by default does *something* ("has a body"), but each child must override that method? And presumably each child must also call the super implementation to make it do its default *something*? Well, you can force a child to implement the method with `abstract`, but you cannot force it to also execute the super implementation. So even if an abstract method with a body was possible, it wouldn't give you any guarantees either.

Comment: @deceze okay, so it wont possible. I realize i am using javascript that this kind of problem will trigger a runtime error which is hard to detect in javascript, that is why i want to do that

Answer (score 1):

Because abstract method purpose is to have its definition in super class and force child classes to override and implement it.

From [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like this:

```
abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);
```

If you want to have an implementation in the abstract method you should not declare method as abstract and remember to override it in child classes calling super method if needed.

Comment: how if we want to have an implementation in the abstract method?

Comment: You don't. That's the entire point. What makes you think you need an abstract method?

Comment: @lubilis : This is exactly why you shouldn't answer questions in a hurry. :). Good luck with the edits.

Comment: that is the problem @lubillis, i just want to add the rule where the other developers will not forget to override it. Thanks for the answer anw

Comment: I think you have "definition" and "declaration" backwards in your opening sentence. The declaration is in the super class. The child classes define it.

Comment: which definition and declaration?

Comment: It should read "Because abstract method purpose is to have its ***declaration*** in super class and force child classes to override and implement it."